# MySQL on Xampp localhost very slow

Tags: php, mysql, yii, xampp

I have a local instance of a large SQL and Yii application. The db is 2.6gb. On the server there is no issue and the site loads with no problems however on local host its crawling to get certain things done, Im talking 10mins in some cases. The PC has 26gb RAM, 8 cores at 2.6ghz and running of a hybrid drive. I've tired modifying the my.ini file:

```
# Example MySQL config file for small systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (<= 64M) where MySQL is only used
# from time to time and it's important that the mysqld daemon
# doesn't use much resources.
#
# You can copy this file to
# E:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is E:/xampp/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
# password       = your_password 
port=3306
socket="E:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysqld]
port=3306
socket="E:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir="E:/xampp/mysql"
tmpdir="E:/xampp/tmp"
datadir="E:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file="mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer=16M
max_allowed_packet=2048M
sort_buffer_size=512K
net_buffer_length=8K
read_buffer_size=256K
read_rnd_buffer_size=512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M
log_error="mysql_error.log"

# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir="E:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/"

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
# commented in by lampp security
#skip-networking
#skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   =1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir = "E:/xampp/tmp"
#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir="E:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir="E:/xampp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "E:/xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3200M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size=1024M
innodb_log_buffer_size=256M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50

## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="E:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"
sql_mode=NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
log_bin_trust_function_creators=1

character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet=16M

[mysql]
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer=20M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer=20M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[mysqlhotcopy]

  #----------------------------------------------------
    #          !!!! Query Cache Config !!!!
    #----------------------------------------------------

    query_cache_size = 524288000
    query_cache_limit = 5242880
    query_cache_type = 1

    #----------------------------------------------------
    #          !!!! InnoDB Buffer Config !!!!
    #----------------------------------------------------

    innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3200M
    innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 200M
    innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
    innodb_log_buffer_size = 10M
    innodb_file_per_table = 1
```

And the php.ini to values of past 2500m but its still very slow. I've added servername as well and use 127.0.0.1:80 but still. Any help would be appreciated since it takes forever to do a fix.

Update: Changed in local db from localhost to 'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1' but still slow.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Running same SQL command comes up very quick in SQL runner.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that mysql is slow? Or do you mean that your phpmyadmin is slow as well?

Comment: Its mysql since the task manager pops it with the largest user of resources coming in at like 90% CPU usage My phpadmin loads up

Comment: So, can you fire an easy query with phpmyadmin like SELECT * FROM ... LIMIT 1? Above there in the green box, there is the time which was needed to complete the request. If the time is very short, the mysql performance is good and phpmyadmin's performance is bad.

Comment: Query took 0.0006 seconds , from a table that has 73000 records in it

Comment: That is very short, so the database is not the problem.
If you say `local host its crawling to get certain things done`, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: So when I run the local instance and navigate to the dashboard its not a problem and some other parts of the website as well. But when I try to pull on certain pages it takes a very long time , on the phpmyadmin the process can be over 500 seconds in some cases even and this is even if I simply refresh the page. Online hosted instance running perfect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243713/discussion-between-john-h-smith-and-rawald).

Answer (score 0):

```
query_cache_size = 524288000
```

Is much to high; limit it to 50M or turn it off.  The query cache purges *all* entries for a given table when *any* change occurs to that table.  The bigger that setting, the slower this maintenance task is.

Please provide that slow query in text so I can analyze it more easily.

I think the whole query boils down to the simply this one-row query:

```
SELECT MIN(t.service_cycle_days) FROM service specification t;
```

except that it might produce no rows (based on the WHERE clause).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v3b2fg5k/ , changed the cache. Though the online instance runs well using the same query

Comment: Were both running the same version of MySQL?

Comment: Yep both running same mySQL version